# How to Divide Multidimensional Array into Single Dimensional Array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array which holds the following data:

Each night is represented by one dimension and in each night there is a date and a list of homework subjects. it is set up like this:

```
HOMEWORK = new String[][]{
    {"TODAY; 5 November 2015", "Math, ILA, Science"},
    {"4 November 2015", "ILA, Science"},
    {"3 November 2015", "Math, ILA, Social Studies"}
};
```

How can I get this to be two single dimensional arrays of the dates and subjects like this?:

```
String[] dates, subjects;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? We can address specific questions, but we can't write your homework for you.

Comment: Even your variable is screaming `Homework`.

Comment: I tried looping through the array and convertin it to an ArrayList but it through exceptions multiple times. @AndyThomas

Comment: "[Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" Voting to close the question.

Comment: @CaptainCucumber - Show us your code and the exceptions, and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
String[] dates = Arrays.stream(HOMEWORK).map(r -> r[0]).toArray(String[]::new);
String[] subjects = Arrays.stream(HOMEWORK).map(r -> r[1]).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: These new streams look funky, but seem to be pretty useful

Answer (score 0):

Start by constructing something to put the values in, you can use arrays and manually grow the arrays, or use something a bit more efficient and easier like a LinkedList or ArrayList

Then move the data from the 2D array into the temporary structures

Finally, convert the temporary structures into your desired arrays

```
List<String> dateList = new LinkedList<String>();
List<String> subjectsList = new LinkedList<String>();
for(String[] entry : HOMEWORK)
{
    subjectsList.add(entry[0];
    dateList.add(entry[1];
}
dates = dateList.toArray(new String[0]);
subjects = subjectsList.toArray(new String[0]);
```

This will only work if your HOMEWORK array is indeed an array of arrays that are length 2, if they are any less then an out-of-bounds exception will be thrown

To prevent that, you can use an if statement to check the length of entry

Answer (score 0):

First create the two String[] to hold the values you're looking for. Then loop through each line of your matrix to copy them.

```
String dates[] = new String[homework.length];
String subjects[] = new String[homework.length];
for (int i = 0; i < homework.length; ++i) {
    dates[i] = homework[i][0];
    subjects[i] = homework[i][1];
}
```

However, you should try by yourself first, show use your code and then ask. Giving you this solution is not going to make you learn to code.
The above code is simple, try to understand why it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that using stream suggested by Jeff Morin is the way to go. If Java 8 is not available, then one way or another you will have to loop through. I am really curious as to how you will be using the two one dimensional arrays in your code.

Personally I would probably try to convert it to a map, which will give me a lot more flexibility in terms of further data processing:

Map homeworkMap = org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils.toMap(homework);

One more thing. Don't you want to format/normalize your data (you've got 'TODAY; 5 November 2015' and '4 November 2015', which will be a nightmare when it comes to search)?